# How to pick one record from multiple rows based on a column value in Db2

Tags: sql, db2

I have the source table as shown below.

Considering today's date as 23-April-2014,  i need to group by Clmn1 value,
if i find multiple records then i need to give preference to '01/01/0001' end date value else i need to give preference to 12/31/9999 end date value.

```
Clmn1   startdate       enddate           Value 
P1         4-Jan-14     12/31/9999      scott   
P1        23-Apr-14     01/01/0001      robert  
P2        4-Mar-14      12/31/9999      sachin  
P2        23-Apr-14    01/01/0001       leo 
P3        1-Apr-14     12/31/9999       Mark    
P4        7-JUly-14    01/01/0001      james
```

Target table:-

```
Clmn1   ValueCurrent    FutureValue
P1            robert      na
P2             leo            na
P3             Mark           na
P4             na            james
```

Comment: are `01/01/0001` and `12/31/9999` the only valid values

Comment: Yes. these are the only values

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple enough.  You're basically getting the row with the lowest end date for each value of `clmn1`:

```
with tmp as (
   select 
      clmn1
     ,startdate
     ,enddate
     ,value
     ,rank() over (partition by clmn1 order by enddate) as rank
   from 
      YOUR_TABLE
)
select 
   clmn1
  ,case 
      when startdate <= current date 
        then value 
      else null end as valuecurrent
  ,case 
      when startdate > current date 
        then value 
      else null end as futurevalue
from 
   tmp
where 
   rank = 1;
```